# PHP date dd/mm and time hh;mm

Tags: php, regex, date, time, format

I'm not sure if I am to use regexp for this or not.
I take two inputs from user, date and time.

I expect the format to be

```
$date = 25/3
$time = 14:30
```

How can I check this? One idea I have is to use like explode or split on for an example $time which leaves me with `14`, `:`, `30`. But what happens if the user enters `144:25?`

Can you advise me of a good way to check that it is the format I want?

Comment: give dropdowns for month day ..and for time also

Comment: If you want to be able to check if the date is valid (i.e., return an error if they put in February 30th) you will need something more complicated that a regex (Though I'm sure there's someone out there that could write some crazy big regex)

Comment: The input should be mm/dd.

Comment: @chrislondon [kaᵠ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/731947) has written a nice regex that takes in account the month february and leap years too. See it [in action](http://regex101.com/r/sE7bN1) !

Comment: @HamZa Haha. I've grown to learn not to say things like "it can't be done" for this reason.  However that regex isn't as ugly as i would've thought

Answer (score 1):

You can check $date with checkdate()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

If you want you can use try and catch block